# My website won't use my custom emoji font (Noto Color Emoji), different behaviour in each browser. Why?

Tags: html, css, fonts, emoji

I'd like to use colored Emojis ony my new project. Therefore I implemented the newest [Noto Color Emoji](https://github.com/googlei18n/noto-emoji/)-Font to my project. My backend is in ASP.NET Core btw.

But now I have a strange behaviour when rendering the emojis on my website, every browser renders it differently, therefore I think my font won't get loaded, maybe?

Edge:

[image: Rendering in Edge]

Firefox:

[image: Rendering in Firefox]

Chrome:

[image: Rendering in Chrome]

As it should be:

[image: As it should be]

site.css:

```
/* fonts*/
@font-face {
    font-family: "color-emoji";
    src: local("Noto Color Emoji");
    src: url("./fonts/NotoColorEmoji.ttf");
}
.emoji {
    font-family: 'color-emoji';
}
```

In my view:

```
<p class="emoji">‍❤‍ ‍❤‍ ‍❤‍</p>
```

This particular emoji is just an example btw.

Do you have any ideas? I know why I am a backend developer in my job. Frontend is killing me all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be on the safe side, one should always use *fully-qualified* emoji zwj sequences.

Instead of:

```
<p class="emoji">‍❤‍ ‍❤‍ ‍❤‍</p>
```

try this:

```
<p class="emoji">‍❤️‍ ‍❤️‍ ‍❤️‍</p>
```

> ‍❤️‍ U+1F469 U+200D U+2764 U+FE0F U+200D U+1F468
>
> ‍❤️‍ U+1F468 U+200D U+2764 U+FE0F U+200D U+1F468
>
> ‍❤️‍ U+1F469 U+200D U+2764 U+FE0F U+200D U+1F469

Note the U+FE0F VARIATION SELECTOR-16 right after the ❤ U+2764 HEAVY BLACK HEART to form a proper red heart emoji...

You can have a look at the [Recommended Emoji ZWJ Sequences, v11.0](https://www.unicode.org/emoji/charts/emoji-zwj-sequences.html) web page, or get a full list of all *fully-qualified* and *non-fully-qualified* emoji in the [emoji-test.txt](https://www.unicode.org/Public/emoji/11.0/emoji-test.txt) data file.

Comment: Thank you so much! That helped me a lot!

I took my emoji list from here:
https://www.google.com/get/noto/help/emoji/smileys-people.html

The U+FE0F segment isn't listed there. Any idea how I can know (other than trial and error) for which emojis it's missing?

Comment: Glad it helped! It's a pity Google does not provide a list of fully-qualified emoji, but they are not the only ones, even Apple's Character Palette can be wrong at times. Personally, I usually rely on the above-mentioned [emoji-test.txt](https://www.unicode.org/Public/emoji/11.0/emoji-test.txt) data file. As for knowing  for which emojis the U+FE0F segment is often missing, I'm afraid I'll have to investigate further more...